# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this `name` object and it says that Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds'). How can I fix this?

```
  const names = [
    {
      displayName: "anna",
      date: { seconds: 1630135912, nanoseconds: 920000000 }
    }
  ];

  console.log(new Date(names.date.seconds * 1000).toDateString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`names` is an array, not an object. You need to index into it to retrieve the first object in the array, and then get the `date` property: `names[0].date.seconds`

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`console.log(new Date(names[0].date.seconds * 1000).toDateString());`